# Is there a Lombok way to initialise a final field that is calculated from other fields?

Tags: java, constructor, initialization, lombok

I'm using Lombok to minimize code. Here's my (contrived) situation in vanilla Java:

```
public class MyClass {
    private final int x;
    private final int sqrt;
    public MyClass(int x) {
        this.x = x;
        sqrt = (int)Math.sqrt(x);
    }
    // getters, etc
}
```

I want to use lombok to generate the constructor and getters:

```
@Getter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyClass {
    private final int x;
    private int sqrt;
}
```

To get the computation into the class, you might consider an instance block:

```
{
    sqrt = (int)Math.sqrt(x);
}
```

but instance blocks are executed *before* code in the constructor executes, so `x` won't be initialized yet.

Is there a way to execute `sqrt = (int)Math.sqrt(x);` *after* `x` is assigned with the constructor argument, but still use the constructor generated by `RequiredArgsConstructor`?

Notes:

- Coding the computation in the getter is not an option (for one, it negates the benefit of using `@Getter`)
- This example is a gross simplification of the real life class, which has many `final` fields, and several computed/derived fields, so the boilerplate savings using lombok are considerable
- The class is a simple POJO DTO, not a managed bean, so none of the lifecycle javax annotations (e.g. `@PostConstruct`) are of any use

Comment: Have you tried using @PostConstruct?

Comment: You're using lombok how about using https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterLazy?

Comment: Maybe you could use inheritance and have `x` initialized in super class constructor that should run before your initialize block.

Comment: it's my bad my first comment was @Lazy from spring (it's late here :p)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about using the [`lazy` option on @Getter](http://projectlombok.org/features/GetterLazy) for the computation:

```
// tested and works OK
@Getter(lazy = true) 
private final int sqrt = (int) Math.sqrt(x);
```

Note: Calling `getSqrt()` works as expected/hoped, firing the computation and setting the "final" field, however accessing the field directly does not invoke the magic - you get the uninitialized value.

Comment: The code can be in-line too `private final int sqrt = (int) Math.sqrt(x);`, thus avoiding the existence of the `compute()` method

Comment: you're gonna have a `null` if you access the variable before you call the getter which seems totally weird like for a **final primitive** https://pastebin.com/5D0tCgaS

Comment: @RC. I took the liberty of leeting up your answer. I also tested the code to make sure it really does work (I agree, this is pretty cool!). Andrew is (unsurprisingly) correct: only access through the getter invokes the magic.

Comment: No problem, and yes, this supposes you only access `sqrt` through the getter (but it's still a pretty cool feature)